# Copy user accounts to new domain, incl SID and passwords etc

Tags: windows-server-2003

I have been tasked with looking into copying users from Prod to a new Pre-Prod environment we're setting up. Its going to be a 2003 environment, (don't ask!, I've had the conversations surrounding upgrading and support expiry!)

Is there a way of copying user accounts to a new domain keeping security and retaining passwords.

I was hoping to be able to script this and during the copy change user accounts to have a prefix of PP_

There is no trust in place between these domains, but I could get firewall opened to allow communication during the copy.

Also while i'm asking would ADMT 3.0 migrate users keeping security, but would it delete the accounts from prod after the migration was complete? That sounds like a silly question because the term migration actually means move, but thought i'd ask :)

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use ADMT to copy accounts across forest and include sidhistory. you can set it to not delete the source.  Yes you can change the account name to have a different prefix etc.  You will need a trust to maintain access to objects in the source forest.  See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc974332(v=ws.10).aspx